# Works of Acharya Utpaladeva from Kashmiri Shavism?

Tags: kashmiri-shaivism

Acharya Utpaladeva was the one who set the base for Kashmiri Shaivism philosophy in order to understand it in a better way. I know 2 of his works i.e. Shivastotravali and Ishwarapratyabijnakarika. Are there any other texts which he wrote? Can someone help to list all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Utpaladeva, a student of Somānanda, wrote a commentary on the Shivadrishti, the Shivadrishtivritti. He also wrote several other works interpreting and furthering the work of Somānanda with much greater sophistication. Those texts are the foundational works of the Pratyabhijnā philosophy of focus in this article. The most comprehensive of these texts are the Īshvarapratyabhijnākārikā, “Verses on the Recognition of the Lord,” and two commentaries on the Verses, the short Īshvarapratyabhijnākārikāvritti, and the more detailed Īshvarapratyabhijnāvivriti. (The latter text has been accessible to contemporary scholars only in fragments.) Utpaladeva also wrote a trilogy of more specialized philosophical studies, the Siddhitrayī, “Three Proofs”—Īshvarasiddhi, “Proof of the Lord;” Ajadapramātrisiddhi, “Proof of a Subject who is not Insentient;” and Sambandhasiddhi, “Proof of Relation.”